# How to add JS & CSS to wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a small code which includes js and CSS files. My website is a wordpress website and I want to add the code to one of my pages.

I want to know where I should place the JS code, and the CSS code, will go in an already made wordpress file or do I have to place them in the directory?

Also for me to implement the code I need to save a few arrays somewhere so that the script can call the arrays back. where do I place the arrays?

Comment: Goto http://google.com that was answered a thousand times already

Comment: look in `functions.php` inside your theme.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to add scripts and styles to your theme is to enqueue them in the functions.php files.

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slider.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

for more information read this document: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/